Dash in \operatorname unavailable with kpfonts-otf
Update: This issue was fixed with a recent release of kpfonts-otf.
I suspect that this is an issue with kpfonts-otf, but you never know. The document was compiled with LuaTeX:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}

$\operatorname{lim-sup}$

\end{document}



UPDATE
Version 0.64 of kpfonts-otf has fixed the issue.
Now the example code works without change.  The produced image is tha same as what was obtained with the older version and the hack below.
For kpfonts-otf version 0.63 or earlier (original answer)
If you add \tracinglostchars=3 to your code, LuaTeX stops with
Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font 
[KpMath-Regular.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;mathfontdimen=xetex;!

(slightly edited for readability). This is quite strange an omission.
I'd complain with the developers of KpMath. In the meantime, you can use the hyphen from the text font.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-45}{\Umathcode`\-="0"5"2010}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\operatorname{lim-sup}$

\end{document}



I wrote them an email.

They released an update on CTAN which fixes the issue (I have tested and confirmed this).

@Gaussler Record time for the update!

Not sure how often it happens that you can make an answer (and get it accepted) which boils down to “just run your MWE, it works”.

@Gaussler It happened…

This is a known challenge with some font packages that either override or redefine certain math font behaviors. However you have a couple of options here that you can you use in order you bypass that. I'll leave you with the one that I would use.
I would renew the command \operatorname to use \mathrm internally. In that way you could continue use the \operatorname as you normally would do. Optionally, you could only substitute the \operatorname with \mathrm. That's up to you!
Here's how you could do it:
\renewcommand{\operatorname}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
[...]
$\operatorname{lim-sup}$

Or simply:
$\mathrm{lim-sup}$

Working result:

Hope it works for you :)

That is not the correct output. Here the - is interpreted as a binary operation.

Perhaps I did not stated in my answer, but I my intention was to provide a similar output with a simple workaround. However I've already understood that my answer is not the best one. I apologise for that. Please do refer to @egreg response for a more similar output.
